# Catch-all/wildcard route in Elixir's Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the Phoenix router is there a route that could act as a wildcard?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Ah, the famous pokemon route:

```
get "/*path"
```

You will find the paths inside `conn.params["path"]` or as `conn.path_info`.

Comment: Ah...took me a while..."Gotta catch 'em all"

Comment: @JoseValim For wildcard routes, how would the path helpers work? For example, let's say you have this line: 


    `get "/*path", RedirectController, :handle_redirect`


how would you write `redirect_path(MyApp.Endpoint, :handle_redirect, ???)`. What would the last argument be? I tried various things and none of them worked.

Comment: IIRC it should be a list of paths: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

Comment: When using this technique I also found it useful to check the value of `conn.request_path`, because it contains the actual path as opposed to the list of path components available in `conn.path_info`.