# How to add a Plug in Elixir / Phoenix before the Router?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there any way to insert a Plug to run prior to the router selecting the controller/action? I've got an app that will redirect to the root path for specific subdomains, regardless of the current path on those domains. So:

`sub.myapp.com/foo/bar` should redirect to `sub.myapp.com/`

But, by default, the Router says there is no path for `/foo/bar` and it halts execution of my plugs, meaning it never hits my redirect.

Is there a way to insert my plug prior to the Router choosing the action/controller?

(Note: I'm pretty sure I can handle this case with [a catch-all route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189311/catch-all-wildcard-route-in-elixirs-phoenix), but I'm just curious if there's a better way.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your router is called explicitly in `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex`. You can add any plugs you like in that file before then.

You can write a plug that handles the redirects and halt the connection before the router is called.

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :hello_phoenix
  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger
  ...
  plug CustomRedirectPlug # Add your plug here
  plug HelloPhoenix.Router
end
```