# How to set a default route in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In node express I can simply do this:

```
app.get("*", function(req, res) {

    res.redirect("/");

});
```

How do I do the equivalent in Phoenix?

I have a basic route,controller, view and template set up per the first exercise in the "Programming Phoenix" book.

**router.ex**

```
 scope "/", Hello do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/hello", HelloController, :world
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end
```

**hello_controller**

```
defmodule Hello.HelloController do
    use Hello.Web, :controller
    def world(conn, _params) do
        render conn, "world.html"
    end
end
```

**hello_view.ex**

```
defmodule Hello.HelloView do
    use Hello.Web, :view
end
```

Comment: Answer is: get "/*path" [This was answered here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189311/catch-all-wildcard-route-in-elixirs-phoenix?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the question because I'm not familiar with nodejs/express but I will assume this is what is happening:

- catch all routes `app.get("*"`
- redirect all routes to `"/"`

#### Method 1: Redirect using a plug before the router plug is called.

*Note:* This method is rather crude and will effectively render all other routes obsolete, all routes will be redirected to the `@route` regardless. The only case I can think of where this might be useful is if a webpage had only a single page to render.

1. Add redirecting plug to the `Endpoint` module. This module has a series of [plugs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/understanding-plug). The file is in `lib/endpoint.ex`

```
defmodule Tester.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :tester

  socket "/socket", Tester.UserSocket

  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/", from: :tester, gzip: false,
    only: ~w(css fonts images js favicon.ico robots.txt)

  plug Plug.RequestId
  plug Plug.Logger

  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison

  plug Plug.MethodOverride
  plug Plug.Head

  plug Plug.Session,
    store: :cookie,
    key: "_tester_key",
    signing_salt: "cS+8eqyy"

  plug Tester.Catch  # <-- Add plug module here or plug function.

  plug Tester.Router

end
```

2. Write the plug module (or function if preferred) `lib/catch.ex`

```
defmodule Tester.Catch do
  @route "/"
  @redirect_to String.split(@route, "/", [trim: :true])

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, opts), do: redirect(conn, opts)

  defp redirect(%{path_info: @redirect_to} = conn, _opts) do
      conn
  end
  defp redirect(%{path_info: _path_info} = conn, _opts) do
      Phoenix.Controller.redirect(conn, to: @route) |> Plug.Conn.halt()
  end

end
```

#### Method 2: Redirect using a phoenix route for catching all other routes that don't match.

*Note:* This method is preferred because due to pattern matching, the matching routes that you probably want to keep will be allowed as long as they are at the top and then you have a catch all route at the bottom of the router.ex scope.

```
defmodule Tester.Router do
  use Tester.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Tester do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/page", PageController, :index
    get "/page/test", PageController, :other

    get "/*path", RedirectController, :redirector
  end

end


defmodule Tester.RedirectController do
  use Tester.Web, :controller
  @send_to "/"

  def redirector(conn, _params), do: redirect(conn, to: @send_to)

end
```

See:

- [redirect_to](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#redirect/2)
- [Previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189311/catch-all-wildcard-route-in-elixirs-phoenix)
- [not found test - phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/test/phoenix/router/routing_test.exs#L37)

Comment: I mentioned in the comment I posted that the answer was already on stack overflow and I found it.

Comment: True, but this answer also provides code for a redirectcontroller. That was helpful for me.