# Creating arbitrarily-nested routes in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm creating a wiki and would like users to be able to construct nested pages for creating categories and the like.

Is it possible to match routes with arbitrary nesting, e.g. `wiki.com/auto_parts/engine/piston` using a single route matcher?

Comment: If you insist on a single route matcher, perhaps a Pokemon route may be of assistance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189311/catch-all-wildcard-route-in-elixirs-phoenix

Comment: Not _just_ one, but I'm allowing for users to have certain amount of space to play with.  Thanks!